# if user role is x - show image - wordpress

Tags: images, uploads, user-roles

I have set up a member portal with ultimate member where users can fill in and submit various forms and then see the answers in a list. Each submitted answer is automatically converted into a pdf.

Each company has a unique role where they can only see the responses of their own role members. Test company has the role "testcompany". There is also an admin for Test company who has the roles "testcompany" and "testcompany admin".

I would like to create a shortcode that automatically retrieves the company logo (the role's logo) and includes this in the form post and the pdf. Right now the user can upload a logo in the form, but it becomes unsustainable if he has to do this every time.

The best thing would be if you could make a page for each admin, where they can upload and change the company's logo if necessary, but **it would also work with a simpler version like:**

You put all logos manually in the folder `wp-content/userlogos/`
Then you name them role names, for example:
*testcompany.jpg*
*testcompany2.jpg*
*testcompany3.jpg*

So if the user has the role *testcompany2*, the image *testcompany2.jpg* should be displayed.

Then you can just add a shortcode where you want to display the logo, and it will be downloaded automatically. Like **[company_logo]**

Should it be possible to add something to functions to make this work?

Found a bunch of switch codes, but that would mean the thread would be really long + I'd have to add new roles to the code, as soon as a new company joins the portal. There must be an easier way?

```php
<?php
$args = array( array('role' => 'administrator', 'img' => '<img src="http://placeape.com/100/100">'),array('role' => 'subscriber', 'img' => '<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">'));
foreach ($args as $arg):
  userLooping($arg['role'], $arg['img']);
endforeach;
?>
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: You could save each of the logo images as an option instead, make the meta key something like `complogo_testcompanyone` and then the meta value is the `src` url for the logo.  You would build the meta key programmatically by getting the role, ie. `testcompanyone` and then prepending it with `complogo_`.  So for any meta data you want to retrieve, you can always build the meta keys on the fly, and you don't have to keep updating the code every time you add a new role. So your shortcode could check for the current users role, then build the meta keys from the role, the get the meta data needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony!
I'm a bit unsure if I understood you correctly, but maybe I don't need that much code for the first example? I have a shortcode called `[um_display_role]` to retrieve the role.

So I should simply name the images testcompany.jpg, testcompany2.jpg etc and only write the following where I want the image?

`<img src="/wp-content/company_logos/[um_display_role].jpg">`
If it was possible to make a shortcode for just this, that would be even better.

The best thing would of course be if the admin for the company could upload and change the logo if needed.

Comment: You would name the logos to match the role, same as if a user uploads it, rename it to match their role, then using your shortcode, you could retrieve the logo because the name of the logo matches the role.  This way even if you're uploading them yourself or the user is uploading, you don't have to write code for each logo, because the names match.  So if user role is `testcompany1` then the logo name would be `testcompany1.jpg`.

Comment: Yes, okay. Will have to test this for now. The best scenario would of course be if the admin for the company could upload the logo himself using, for example, gravity form. In this way, additional administration would be avoided. But then you have to make sure that only one file can be uploaded per admin, that it ends up in the right place, that it gets a unique role name and that it can be edited or replaced.
Would be grateful if someone could help me with that?

Comment: That can all be done, I've built something similar (for users to upload profile photos) but no one can just 'help you with it'... ...you've got to start working on it and then when you encounter a step that you can't resolve, post a question here.  I can't just dump all my code for the similar function here for you because you still won't be able to use it, it's dependent on a myriad of other functions.  What I do is allow users to upload an image, then I rename the image to `lastname-firstname.ext` and add it in a custom directory in the uploads folder.  Usual sanitization, file checks, etc.

Comment: Okay. I will try to accomplish something similar. Tried it before with a little javascript, but it turned out to be a bit too much cut, paste and amateurish. I'm even worse at php, so thought I'd check if there was something I could start with. But I have to try.